# file not getting deleted programmatically in asp.net

Tags: .net-2.0

I'm not able to delete the file programmatically in asp.net. No Error is coming. But even then file is not getting deleted.

Comment: Please post the code you are using to delete the file. We are not mind readers, you know...

Comment: string filen = lblfilename.Text; this is the which im uploading
       
        if (filen.Length > 0)
        {
            string fi = "C:\\Inetpub\\wwwroot\\printsite\\CivilIDImagesPath\\" + filen;
            File.Delete(fi);
          

        }

Answer (score 0):

By default ASP.Net runs apps under the ASPNET account - has that account been given sufficient file permissions to delete the file?

Comment: wat code i should use to delete the file. have u got any idea.. i need to implement ASAP

Comment: I just quickly read the MS documentation for File.Delete (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx) and it says that the only time it doesn't give an error is when the file doesn't exist.

Forget what I said about permissions, you'd be getting an UnauthorizedAccessException if that was the case.

Are you absolutely sure the path in "fi" is correct??

Comment: My Recquirement is like if by mistakenly the user might have uploaded the file and the user will delete the file and again he will upload a new file.